# Get System Volume iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, audio, volume

My case is simple:
I need to play a warning signal and want to make sure the user will hear it, so I want to check the system volume.

How can I find out what the current system volume is?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Update for Swift**

```
let vol = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
```

The audio session can provide output volume (iOS >= 6.0).

```
float vol = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume];
NSLog(@"output volume: %1.2f dB", 20.f*log10f(vol+FLT_MIN));
```

Comment: I use in iOS 11 in today extension - sometimes it doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872409/avaudiosessions-outputvolume-never-changes/52284131#52284131 -try playing audio then checking. Had same proble, worked for me.

Comment: Make sure to also do `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)` first or this value will not update when the volume is changed

Comment: Just a little niggle: the value returned is not a ratio/gain which can be directly converted to decibels like this. The value directly reflects the position of the volume indicator, and Apple aren't advertising how that relates to an actual gain or decibel value. Most likely it's a scale mapped to a decibel range, but it's anyone's guess what the scale is.

Answer (score 16):

**Swift 3.1**

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
var volume: Float?
do {
    try audioSession.setActive(true)
    volume = audioSession.outputVolume
} catch {
    print("Error Setting Up Audio Session")
}
```

`audioSession.setActive(true)` - **important**

Comment: Can you share why setActive(true) is important?

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *iPod = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
float volumeLevel = iPod.volume;
```

You need to import the MediaPlayer framework.

Comment: It is deprecated, use [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume] instead.

Answer (score 12):

This works fine:

```
Float32 volume;
UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(Float32);

AudioSessionGetProperty (
                     kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume,
                     &dataSize,
                     &volume
                     );
```

Comment: Even better in my case! Now I can ditch the MediaPlayer Framework.

Comment: This is deprecated in iOS 7 - does anybody know the new way?

Answer (score 12):

For **Swift 2**:

```
let volume = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume   
print("Output volume: \(volume)")
```

Comment: We also need `audioSession.setActive(true)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the default system's volume View and add to wherever you need it. In my case I required it in my own music player. It's easy and hassle free. Just add the view, and everything is done. This is explained in Apple's [MPVolume Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
mpVolumeViewParentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
MPVolumeView *myVolumeView =
[[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: mpVolumeViewParentView.bounds];
[mpVolumeViewParentView addSubview: myVolumeView];
[myVolumeView release];
```

Comment: The question was not how to provide the user with a way of changing the volume, but how to detect if the volume was high enough. How does this answer help?

Comment: True not particularly relevant to the question but still useful within the greater context of how to adjust system volume.

Answer (score 2):

I have prepared a class with static methods in order to deal with the volume of ios devices. Let me share with you :)

```
import AVFoundation
class HeadPhoneDetectHelper {
class func isHeadPhoneConnected() -> Bool
{
    do{
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
        let currentRoute = audioSession.currentRoute
        let headPhonePortDescriptionArray = currentRoute.outputs.filter{$0.portType == AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones}
        let isHeadPhoneConnected = headPhonePortDescriptionArray.count != 0
        return isHeadPhoneConnected
    }catch{
        print("Error while checking head phone connection : \(error)")
    }
    return false
}

class func isVolumeLevelAppropriate() -> Bool
{
    let minimumVolumeLevelToAccept = 100
    let currentVolumeLevel = HeadPhoneDetectHelper.getVolumeLevelAsPercentage()
    let isVolumeLevelAppropriate = currentVolumeLevel >= minimumVolumeLevelToAccept
    return isVolumeLevelAppropriate
}

class func getVolumeLevelAsPercentage() -> Int
{
    do{
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
        let audioVolume =  audioSession.outputVolume
        let audioVolumePercentage = audioVolume * 100
        return Int(audioVolumePercentage)
    }catch{
        print("Error while getting volume level \(error)")
    }
    return 0
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.2, make sure to import MediaPlayer

```
private func setupVolumeListener()
{
    let frameView:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: frameView)
    //self.window?.addSubview(volumeView) //use in app delegate
   self.view.addSubview(volumeView)  //use in a view controller


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(volumeChanged(_:)), name: "AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification", object: nil)
}//eom



func volumeChanged(notification:NSNotification)
{
    let volume = notification.userInfo!["AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"]
    let category = notification.userInfo!["AVSystemController_AudioCategoryNotificationParameter"]
    let reason = notification.userInfo!["AVSystemController_AudioVolumeChangeReasonNotificationParameter"]

    print("volume:      \(volume!)")
    print("category:    \(category!)")
    print("reason:      \(reason!)")
    print("\n")
}//eom
```