# How to get System Volume iOS?

Tags: avfoundation, audiotoolbox

I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255006/get-system-volume-ios), but it does not work on ios6.1.3 (iphone 4s).
always return 0.187500

Code:

```
Float32 volume;
UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(Float32);

AudioSessionInitialize (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
AudioSessionGetProperty (
                     kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume,
                     &dataSize,
                     &volume
                     );
NSLog(@"%f", volume);
```

[AVAudioSession sharedInstance].outputVolume - also return 0.187500

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize the audio session with:

```
AudioSessionInitialize (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

in `viewDidLoad` or similar.

However, it's generally a better idea to make use of the new [AVAudioSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVAudioSession/sharedInstance) class if you're targeting iOS 6+, which handles that for you:

```
float volume = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].outputVolume;
```

Comment: I have tried paste AudioSessionInitialize (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);, now always return 0.187500, volume on full.

Comment: [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].outputVolume -  also return 0.187500

Answer (score 4):

float volume = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume];

Comment: The best answers have some explanation as well as code. Please consider adding some context.