# Get and set volume on iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

How to get and set the volume in iOS xamarin.forms?

I have written a dependacy service in android which sets and gets the volume of the music stream on android.

I want to have a slider with the current volume set by default and allower user to set the volume by sliding the slider. Also I would like to get the maximum allowed volume level for setting the maximum limit of the slider.

Here is how I have done in android, and is working perfectly on andriod device:

```
public int MaxVolume()
{
    AudioManager audioMan = (AudioManager)global::Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
    return audioMan.GetStreamMaxVolume(Android.Media.Stream.Music);
}

public void SetVolume(int volume)
{
    AudioManager audioMan = (AudioManager)global::Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
    audioMan.SetStreamVolume(Android.Media.Stream.Music, volume, 0);
}

public int GetCurrentVolume()
{
    AudioManager audioMan = (AudioManager)global::Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
    return audioMan.GetStreamVolume(Android.Media.Stream.Music);
}
```

How do I achieve same on iOS? I tried `float volume = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().OutputVolume;`, but doesn't give me volume.

Answer (score 0):

To Specify volume u need to use AVPlayer

```
 AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback , AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers);

 var player = new AVPlayer(audioFilePath);
 player.Volume = 0.2f;  
 player.Play();
```

Where sound level goes from 0.0f to 1f

[More about AVPlayer](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/sound/avaudioplayer/)

If you need to rise or low it just add the value. Also you can have a look at [MPVolumeView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/)
This is a slider that changes volume programmatically

Comment: How do I get maximum volume?

Comment: Why do you need to know the volume level?

Comment: That is because I have a slider which allows use to control the volume and I need to set maximum volume to the slider.

Comment: Check out MPVolumeView

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this (get the current output volume only):

```
AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().SetActive(true);
return AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().OutputVolume;
```

The first instruction is required to get updated values, the second returns a float between 0 and 1 indicating the current output volume.

Thanks to these references:

output volume: [Get System Volume iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255006/get-system-volume-ios)

update the value: [How to get System Volume iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257199/how-to-get-system-volume-ios)